# How does b-trees reduce the search time of a particular file?

Tags: data-structures, filesystems, b-tree

in general file systems...

If external data are stored in it's leaves, then what exactly is stored in the leaf? Is it binary data? The whole file or a piece of it? ... Pointers to other blocks?

I know, based on the selection of B, we can load all the internal nodes into memory and a search path will start in internal memory and end up in one of the leaves. But how does disk block sizes have anything to do with storing the leaves externally?

If a file we're storing is greater than the disk block size, 4096 bytes, does it occupy more than one leaf or does it get it's own internal nodes? How does this affect the search time?

Comment: Are we talking about database indices here? Or a B-tree-based filesystem? Or both or neither?

Comment: @hobbs file system only